# python attrs inherited field value gets overwritten

Tags: python, inheritance, python-attrs

I have some `attrs` classes that inherit from a base class. The parent class has a field that is also an attrs class.

If I instantiate two instances of the child classes and set the common inherited field's sub-field, the other instance's field gets overwritten as well.

I could work around this by using a `factory` for the field to specify the required default value with a `partial` (method 3).

As it seems, with methods 1 and 2, the instantiation of `MyField` for the default value only takes place once, and is somehow shared (?) between the child instances (?)

Is there any other way without this hack?

Here is the code:

```py
import functools
import attrs


def test_attrs_problem():

    @attrs.define
    class MyField:
        name: str
        value: int = 0

    @attrs.define
    class Parent:
        # Test fails with the following two field definitions:
        #  --- method 1 ---
        # a: MyField = MyField(name="default_name")
        #  --- method 2 ---
        # a: MyField = attrs.field(default=MyField(name="default_name"))

        # Test passes with the following two field definitions:
        #  --- method 3 ---
        a: MyField = attrs.field(
            factory=functools.partial(
                MyField,
                name="default_name"
            )
        )

    @attrs.define
    class Child1(Parent):
        b: int = 42

    @attrs.define
    class Child2(Parent):
        c: int = 43

    # creating an instance of the Child1 class
    c1 = Child1()
    c1.a.value = 1
    before = c1.a.value
    print("before", c1)

    # creating a instance of the Child2 class
    c2 = Child2()
    # setting the common inherited field's value field for the c2 instance
    c2.a.value = 2
    after = c1.a.value
    print("after", c1)

    # expecting that the value in the c1 instance is the same
    assert after == before
```

Comment: Of course it also works with this: `a: MyField = attrs.field(factory=lambda: MyField(name="default_name"))`

Comment: Well, if I think it through, I guess it totally makes sense, as in method 1 and 2 the value is stored as a reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is a special case of the classic:

```py
from attrs import define

@define
class C:
    a: list = []
```

Unless you use factories, there's only *one* instance of `MyField` that is used by all instances of C and their subclasses.

As you've found out, if you want a separate `MyField` per instance, you have to create every time.

I personally find the following approach more idiomatic:

```py
@attrs.define
class MyField:
    name: str
    value: int = 0

@attrs.define
class Parent:
    a: MyField = attrs.Factory(lambda: MyField(name="default_name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is this: a helper function to create the field with the factory boilerplate:

```py
def my_field(**kwargs):
    return attrs.field(factory=lambda: MyField(**kwargs))
```

and then use this:

```py
@attrs.define
class Parent:
    a: MyField = my_field(...)
```